# Correct usage of boolean logic in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I apologise for the question, but it's left me a little baffled.

To start with, I have a set of address objects, and I am trying to find relevant ones with a query that would (in pseudocode) look something like this

```
SELECT
WHERE
     Fuzzy(addr1, "address line 1) // = true
AND
     (Fuzzy(addr2, "address line 2") OR
      Fuzzy(addrcity, "address city") OR
      //all the other address fields
     )
```

Essentially I want to bring back all entities where at least address line one matches roughly, and one of the other parts of the address also has a fuzzy match.

I have verified that the data is there via this query:

```
Query toRun = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addr1", getLineOne()));
```

Which returns the document which has all of the correct fields.

My code is below:

```
public List<Address> search() {
    List<Address> results = new ArrayList<>();

    BooleanQuery.Builder queryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    queryBuilder.setMinimumNumberShouldMatch(2);

    BooleanQuery.Builder subQueryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    subQueryBuilder.setMinimumNumberShouldMatch(1);

    if(!getLineOne().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addr1", getLineOne()));
        queryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    }

    if(!getLineTwo().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addr2", getLineTwo()));
        subQueryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
    if(!getCity().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addrcity", getCity()));
        subQueryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
    if(!getCounty().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addrcounty", getCounty()));
        subQueryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
    if(!getCountry().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addrcountry", getCountry()));
        subQueryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
    if(!getPostcode().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addrpostcode", getPostcode()));
        subQueryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }

    queryBuilder.add(subQueryBuilder.build(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

    try {
        Query toRun = queryBuilder.build();

        List<Document> searchResults = SearchEngine.getInstance(SEARCH_ENGINE)
                .performSearch(toRun, 50);

        searchResults.forEach(result -> {
            results.add(new Address(result));
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return results;
}
```

This produces, when the object is supplied with a line one, line two and a country a query that looks like this in text form:

(+addr1:address line 1~2 +((addr2:address line 2~2 addrcountry:romania~2)~1))~2

Which as mentioned returns nothing.

Where am I going wrong in my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the first minimumShouldMatch call.

`setMinimumNumberShouldMatch` specifies how many `SHOULD` clauses must match.  Your   `queryBuilder` has no `SHOULD` clauses, so it obviously can't match two of them, thus you get no results.

You could just delete both of the `setMinimumNumberShouldMatch` lines, and have a query that works correctly.  Alternatively, you could use the minimumShouldMatch logic and simplify to use only one BooleanQuery, like this:

```
public List<Address> search() {
    List<Address> results = new ArrayList<>();

    BooleanQuery.Builder queryBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    queryBuilder.setMinimumNumberShouldMatch(1);

    if(!getLineOne().equals("")) {
        //This is a MUST clause, and so doesn't factor into the minimumShouldMatch
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addr1", getLineOne()));
        queryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    }

    if(!getLineTwo().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addr2", getLineTwo()));
        queryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
    if(!getCity().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addrcity", getCity()));
        queryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
    if(!getCounty().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addrcounty", getCounty()));
        queryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
    if(!getCountry().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addrcountry", getCountry()));
        queryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }
    if(!getPostcode().equals("")) {
        Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("addrpostcode", getPostcode()));
        queryBuilder.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }

    try {
        Query toRun = queryBuilder.build();

        List<Document> searchResults = SearchEngine.getInstance(SEARCH_ENGINE)
                .performSearch(toRun, 50);

        searchResults.forEach(result -> {
            results.add(new Address(result));
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you. I thought it meant how many out of all the booleans at least should be true but that is logical